# How do I automatically redirect the user if they are already logged in using Vue and Firebase authentication?

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

**Description**

I am trying to automatically route the user to the "Games.vue" component if they are already logged in. For authentication I am using Firebase and I check if they are logged in using:

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user) {
  // User is signed in.
} else {
  // No user is signed in.
}
```

What I want to have happen is for the user to not see the Login page if they are already signed in. So they are taken directly to the Games page. I don't know how to accomplish this using Vue. I need something to run before the Login-component that redirects if logged in.

**Attempt at solution**

The only way I know how to solve this is to show the Login page, check if the Firebase user is logged in and then go to the Games page. This can work, but it isn't the behavior I am looking for. I am using the Vue router. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a VueRouter global guard like so:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({ ... })

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (!user) {
    next('login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

That being said, you then need a way to specify which route requires authentication. I would suggest to use route meta fields like so:

```js
routes = [
  {
    name: 'login',
    path: '/login',
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: false
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'games',
    path: '/games',
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  }
]
```

Now your guards becomes:

```js
if (!user && to.meta.requiresAuth) {
  next('login');
} else {
  next();
}
```

Vue router provides an example for this use case, take a look at [the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html#route-meta-fields).

**TIP:** Make sure to subscribe to auth changes using Firebase `onAuthStateChanged` method.

```js
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  user = user;
});
```

**EDIT:** To redirect once logged in, just watch for auth changes and  redirect using `router.push`.

```js
auth.onAuthStateChanged(newUserState => {
  user = newUserState;
  if (user) {
    router.push("/games");
  }
});
```

Comment: What this does is checks whether or not a user exists and takes you to the login page if authentication is required and no user exists. That is fine, but what I want to accomplish is to have login redirect to the games if you are logged in.

Comment: I edited my answer to redirect once logged in.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!